# Прямая речь. О знаках препинания

Tags: прямая-речь, пунктуация

Как правильно расставлять знаки препинания в прямой речи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаки препинания зависят от положения прямой речи относительно слов автора.
1. Если слова автора стоят после прямой речи, то порядок следующий: открытые кавычки, текст речи, знак препинания (восклицательный или вопросительный), закрытые кавычки, запятая (если не было ни восклицательного, ни вопросительного знака), тире, авторская речь с маленькой буквы.
Пример: *"Собака", - подумал Штирлиц. "Сам ты собака!" - подумала собака.*
2. Если авторский текст стоит перед прямой речью: слова автора с большой буквы, двоеточие, открытые кавычки, прямая речь с большой буквы, знак препинания, закрытая кавычка. Внимание: после закрытых кавычек точка не ставится!
Пример: *Он так и сказал: "Нельзя!"*
3. Слова автора стоят в середине прямой речи: открытые кавычки, прямая речь с большой буквы, запятая, тире, слова автора с маленькой буквы, запятая или точка (в таком случае вторая часть прямой речи начнется с большой буквы), тире, вторая часть прямой речь, знак препинаня, закрытые кавычки.
Примеры: *"Не могу точно сказать, - вздохнул он, - но похоже, что так..."*
4. Прямая речь находится внутри авторских слов: слова автора с большой буквы, двоеточие, открытые кавычки, прямая речь с большой буквы, закрытые кавычки, запятая, тире, слова автора с маленькой буквы, точка.
Пример: *Он сказал: "Вот, так все и было", - и вздохнул.*

Answer (score 0):

Он сказал: "Вот, так все и было" - и вздохнул.

Запятая перед тире не нужна.